# DIV that re-sizes height to match content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I am currently using Bootstrap to design a website. My page has content in a div tag that spans across the entire width of the page (width: 100%), however I have to set my height using a numeric px value (i.e "250px") or else the div spans the entire page from top to bottom, this also happens if I take out the width and ass a min-width. Is there anyway I can set a min-width and then have the div expand should it need to. Here is my relevant CSS code:

```
.cd {
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);

    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    margin: auto;
    padding: 30px;
    padding-left: 25%;
    padding-right: 25%;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/7yefuqd9/)

Comment: Why do you need position absolute? What happens if you take that off? Divs should hug the content, height wise, so there might be some CSS in there doing something. Adding a jsfiddle may help.

Comment: Add working code snippet here or on http://jsfiddle.net please.

Comment: Ok, I've added a link to my original post.

Comment: Are you using absolute positioning to get the div vertically centered? I would recommend flexbox for that, if your browser support policy allows for it. Otherwise you may need to resort to minor CSS hacks like using `display: table;` on the parent and `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle` on the child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it takes the whole height cause you are using absolute positioning and you are setting the bottom value to zero

if you do need the absolute positioning you can just modify the css to the following

```
.cd {
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);

    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    margin: auto;
    padding: 30px;
    padding-left: 25%;
    padding-right: 25%;
}
```

edit to make it centered vertically

```
.cdc {
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    margin: auto;
    padding: 30px;
    padding-left: 25%;
    padding-right: 25%;
}
```

Comment: I have `bottom: 0;` because I want the DIV centered on the page. I've also added a link to jsfiddle to my original post.

Comment: It works when resizing, however the div is now twice as large, so the content ends and there is still quite  bit of black space under it.

Comment: yeah that's cause I forgot to take off the bottom value, check the edited css again

Comment: Thanks that seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Your div is taking the full height of the page because of the `position: absolute` with `top: 0` and `bottom: 0`. That combination will stretch a div to fill the full height of its container. Your best bet is to get rid of the absolute positioning entirely.

Edit: Saw JSFiddle, cribbing my comment from the top-level to here:

I would recommend flexbox for vertical centering elements, if your browser support policy allows for it. Otherwise you may need to resort to minor CSS hacks like using display: table; on the parent and display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle on the child.

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle link to my original post.

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing

```
height: 250px;
```

with

```
height: auto;
```

Comment: `height: auto` just stretches the height to 100%.